Swagger API documentation, define array in url
Following the documentation of Swagger I've been able to document most of my API. The one I'm stuck on seems to be an array in the GET url.
What this generates is:
http://localhost/[some_url]/?users=10&users=20&page=1
instead of what I (Laravel) need(s):
http://localhost/[some_url]/?users[]=10&users[]=20&page=1
My configuration is:
@OA\Get(
    path="/api/[some_url]",
    tags={"Description goes here"},
    summary="Summary goes here",
    @OA\Parameter(
        description="Users",
        in="query",
        name="users",
        required=false,
        example="[10, 20]",
        @OA\Schema(type="array", @OA\Items(type="integer"))
    ),
    @OA\Parameter(
        description="Page",
        in="query",
        name="page",
        required=false,
        example="1",
        @OA\Schema(type="integer")
    ),
    @OA\Response(
        response="200",
        description="OK (successfully authenticated)",
        @OA\JsonContent()
    )
)


I've never been able to make that (or deep objects for that matter) work in a dynamic way.
What you can do, is define the users[0] and users[1] parameters in your phpdoc blocks and swagger ui will make them work. It's good enough for an example at least.

Does it work if you use name="users[]"?

unfortunately it just url encodes the bracket... It would have been great though
